# How do I store and print elements from document.getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am reading in values from a HTML form. Let's say 10 values. I want to take these values and store them in an array so I can access them later and add/subtract/multiply them. I am trying to print these values as well.

I get all sorts of errors from HTMLCollection to HTMLDivElement etc. I've tried .nodeValue, .value. Looked up converting HTMLCollection to an array. but no luck.

I've tried everything at this point but can't seem to figure it out. Here's what I have currently.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction here? 
Thank you

```
var valueArray = new Array();
valueArray = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
document.write(valueArray[0]);
```

```
var valueArray = document.getElementByClassName("data");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   document.write(valueArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `valueArray[i].value` should get what you're looking for

Comment: Can you please show your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.from` to turn it into an array and map out the `value` simultaneously:

```js
const values = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("data"), ({ value }) => parseInt(value));
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<input class="data" value="123">
<input class="data" value="456">
```

Comment: Thanks Jack! All of these responses worked. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem whatsoever @user11467841!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get a array of `value` property of all elements with specific class. You can use `querySelectorAll()` and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var valueArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".data")].map(x => x.value);
```

If you want to add/multiply... the values you should convert it to number using Unary Plus `+`

```
var valueArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".data")].map(x => +x.value || x.value);
```

Below is a demo.

```js
var valueArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".data")].map(x => +x.value || x.value);
console.log(valueArray)
```

```html
<input value="55" class="data" />
<input value="90" class="data" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Maheer. All of these responses worked and showed me some good ways to pull the data so I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user11467841 You should accept the answer that you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this to get the `HTMLCollection` inside an array:

```
var elements = document.getElementByClassName("data");
var arrayOfElements = [...elements];
```

First get the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by method `getElementsByClassName()` and then spread that `HTMLCollection` inside an array. You can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) too:

```
var arrayOfElements = Array.from(elements);
```

Example, including also the map to values:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
var arrayOfElements = [...elements].map(e => e.value);
// Or:
// var arrayOfElements = Array.from(elements, e => e.value);

console.log(arrayOfElements);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<input id="i1" type="text" class="data" value="val1">
<input id="i2" type="text" class="data" value="val2">
```

If you need to save the `values` as numbers, then you can use the [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()):

```
var arrayOfElements = [...elements].map(e => +e.value);
```